# На какой строке нажата клавиша?

Tags: c#

Есть gatagridview. Как определить, на какой строке нажата клавиша?
Можно ли это сделать событием keydown? В нем я могу узнать только, какая клавиша нажата...

Comment: укажите фреймворк?

Comment: И толку от фреймворка?

Как я понимаю, нужен CurrentRow.Index или DataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex, если у вас выделяется вся строка.

Comment: @Magos: Например тем, что в WPF нет `CurrentRow`?

Comment: @DreamChild WinForms

Comment: у меня строка с несколькими ячейками, выбрали нужную строку, нажали SPACE и дальше в каком событии искать нажатую клавишу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подписывайся на `KeyDown`, и в обработчике проверяй `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index`.

Comment: Прокатило с dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Index
Спасибо!

@Magos, так же спасибо! ваш вариант не пробовал, но теперь понял что верный ответ был дан вами:)

Answer (score 0):

а если у вас несколько DataGrid? я бы добавил в обработчик

```
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
```